# How do I use eclipse with python (pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page explains how to use eclipse with C++: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Eclipse.
This page explains how to set up eclipse with pydev to edit python files: [https://wiki.nps.edu/display/~thchung/ROS+--+Using+the+Eclipse+IDE](https://wiki.nps.edu/display/%7Ethchung/ROS+--+Using+the+Eclipse+IDE)

But nothing seems to tell me how to actually run python ros packages under eclipse, set breakpoints, etc. When I try to run it fails with an exception when trying to load the manifest:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bouchier/ros_workspace/randomWalk/src/randomWalker.py", line 6, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('randomWalk')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 118, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 157, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/rospack.py", line 149, in get_path
    raise ResourceNotFound(name, ros_paths=self._ros_paths)
rospkg.common.ResourceNotFound: randomWalk
```

I've single-stepped through rosserial_python (which is what I really want to run in a debugger), and it gets the same error. I've tried running from different directories, & it seems to be unable to find manifest.xml when running in eclipse. (It runs fine from rosrun).

How do python developers do debugging? Is there an easy fix to use eclipse? Any other toolsets I should be using?

Thanks

Paul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37142/how-do-i-use-eclipse-with-python-(pydev)/) by [PaulBouchier](https://answers.ros.org/users/2700/paulbouchier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 300 on 2012-06-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Paul,

as far as I know there is no direct support yet to launch ros nodes out of eclipse (and debug them). I use eclipse with pydev to develop the node but I still run it from the console with rosrun.

There has been done some effort by the guys from TU Munich to integrate the ros tools into an IDE, but I don't know how far the project is and if it is still actively developed. You can find the source in this [repository](http://code.in.tum.de/indefero/index.php//p/rosclipse/).

You could try to execute rosrun as an external run script in eclipse. I tried to set it up once but gave up because I could not find a way to properly set up all the paths ros has set in the console (through setup.bash). There is probably a way but I decided its not worth it.

Good luck

Felix

---

Originally posted by [Felix Kaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2655/felix-kaser/) with karma: 318 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-06-26**:
tum rosclipse project is dormant, pydev integration was not even on the todo list yet.